# Top bar break point - Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I have upgraded from Foundation 4 to Foundation 5, and I am trying to set up a custom break point in the top bar **without** using Sass.

In foundation 4 you were able to change the following css code in the foundation.css file:

```
.top-bar-js-breakpoint {
  width: 48em !important;
  ...
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
   ...
}
```

But this isn't possible with Foundation 5, atleast I am not able to find the piece of CSS or JS code to change it.

I have also tried redownloading a new custom foundation installation with the `TOP BAR BREAKPOINT` set to 9999em, which just does not work. Even after removing all previous files and code.

This simple problem is driving me nuts, so it would be great if someone would put me out my misery with a simple sollution, please!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the `meta.foundation-mq-topbar` css selector in your code and change `width` attribute value to 48em or any other size you want.

Another solution:
Foundation separate components media query from each other, so you can change breakpoint for each components. Look at this code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .top-bar {
    background: #333333;
    *zoom: 1;
    overflow: visible; }
    .top-bar:before, .top-bar:after {
      content: " ";
      display: table; }
    .top-bar:after {
      clear: both; }
    .top-bar .toggle-topbar {
      display: none; }
    .top-bar .title-area {
      float: left; }
    .top-bar .name h1 a {
      width: auto; }
    .top-bar input,
    .top-bar .button {
      font-size: 0.875rem;
      position: relative;
      top: 7px; }
    .top-bar.expanded {
      background: #333333; }

  .contain-to-grid .top-bar {
    max-width: 62.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0; }

  .top-bar-section {
    -webkit-transition: none 0 0;
    -moz-transition: none 0 0;
    transition: none 0 0;
    left: 0 !important; }
    .top-bar-section ul {
      width: auto;
      height: auto !important;
      display: inline; }
      .top-bar-section ul li {
        float: left; }
        .top-bar-section ul li .js-generated {
          display: none; }
    .top-bar-section li.hover > a:not(.button) {
      background: #272727;
      color: white; }
    .top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
      padding: 0 15px;
      line-height: 45px;
      background: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
        background: #272727; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a {
      padding-right: 35px !important; }
      .top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: inset 5px;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) transparent transparent transparent;
        border-top-style: solid;
        margin-top: -2.5px;
        top: 22.5px; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved {
      position: relative; }
      .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.moved > .dropdown {
        display: none; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.hover > .dropdown, .top-bar-section .has-dropdown.not-click:hover > .dropdown {
      display: block; }
    .top-bar-section .has-dropdown .dropdown li.has-dropdown > a:after {
      border: none;
      content: "\00bb";
      top: 1rem;
      margin-top: -2px;
      right: 5px; }
    .top-bar-section .dropdown {
      left: 0;
      top: auto;
      background: transparent;
      min-width: 100%; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li a {
        color: white;
        line-height: 1;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 12px 15px;
        background: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li label {
        white-space: nowrap;
        background: #333333; }
      .top-bar-section .dropdown li .dropdown {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0; }
    .top-bar-section > ul > .divider, .top-bar-section > ul > [role="separator"] {
      border-bottom: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: solid 1px #4d4d4d;
      clear: none;
      height: 45px;
      width: 0; }
    .top-bar-section .has-form {
      background: #333333;
      padding: 0 15px;
      height: 45px; }
    .top-bar-section ul.right li .dropdown {
      left: auto;
      right: 0; }
      .top-bar-section ul.right li .dropdown li .dropdown {
        right: 100%; }

  .no-js .top-bar-section ul li:hover > a {
    background: #272727;
    color: white; }
  .no-js .top-bar-section ul li:active > a {
    background: #2ba6cb;
    color: white; }
  .no-js .top-bar-section .has-dropdown:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block; }
}
```

You have to find the above code and just change this media query for changing top bar breakpoint.

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately it doesn't seem that changing `width` attribute after `meta.foundation-mq-topbar` works on its own. However if I change `@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em)` then it changes my 'small' screen range, which i don't want to change. Any ideas?

Comment: @deacs I complete my answer, look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I have the CSS changes pinned after the SCSS compiles.

Search for `.top-bar` in your CSS and look for the entry similar to the below, and change "981px" as needed:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {
.top-bar {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7d7d 0%, #646464 100%);
    *zoom: 1;
    overflow: visible
}
```

Search for `meta.foundation-mq-topbar` in your CSS and change "981px" as needed:

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
    font-family: "/only screen and (min-width: 981px)/";
    width: 981px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically what i did to make it work after reading the solution from Parhum. Search for the
meta.foundation-mq-topbar. There should be a width corresponding to it, in my case which is the 40.063em.This one has to be changed. Now, look for the corresponding media query (i.e. @media only screen and (min-width:40.063em)) Change BOTH of the width in both of the line. It should be working fine now.

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.00em)/";
width: 64.00em !the width of this must change; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.00em) {
.top-bar {
background: #333333;
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, if you just change the "@media only ..." line as the selected answer suggests, it will display correctly, however the button won't work so the menu doesn't open. You have to change the "meta.foundation-mq-topbar { ..." as well in order to make it work.